# Detect property selection in propertyGrid

Tags: c#, properties, selection, detect, propertygrid

Is it possible to detect when a property in a propertyGrid is selected? And if so, how?

In the following picture, I would like to know which of the properties is selected at runtime.
[image]

For example, The Grid knows that MyBool is selected, what can I do to get that information programatically instead of visually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't to often work in windows forms apps but was bored and thought I'd take a look.  I'm not sure you've provided all the context to what you're looking for but just going on question I would suggest

```
private void propertyGrid1_SelectedGridItemChanged(object sender, SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.NewSelection.Label);

    }
```

Hopefully this helps.